# Android pre-loading page so that till the time app loads that page is visible

Tags: android

Can anyone put me on the right path so that i'm able to develop a Pre-loading page which is visible till the application loads in background.

Comment: I think you are talking about a splash screen.Just use  `AsyncTask` to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Tanmay : can you give a link of some example or tutorial as i'm a newbbie to android and am finding it quite difficult

Comment: hope this will help you http://sirinsevinc.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/118/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use an `AsyncTask` implementation for loading your application in a background thread.

In the `AsyncTask`'s

1. `onPreExecute` method you display an
   image (splash screen / loading
   spinner / progress dialog...),
2. `doInBackground` method you load the
   necessary data for your application
   to start, and in the
3. `onPostExecute` method you remove
   the preloader image, and display
   your application which already has
   all the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement a thread which will show an image related to your application.
After some time you call your first Activity.